# Errors with ruby-prof in a Rails Performance Test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-prof

I'm creating a Rails Performance test, as described in the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#installing-gc-patched-mri), and I'm having problems with ruby-prof.

I'm using Ruby 1.9.2-p0 (though experienced the same issue on p320) and Rails 3.1.0.

I have a pretty simple test for a controller that is equivalent to [this example](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#controller-example).

According to [the guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/performance_testing.html#using-ruby-prof-on-mri-and-ree), I need to install ruby-prof before I can use performance tests. Sure enough, if I run my performance test without it, I get:

> Specify ruby-prof as application's dependency in Gemfile to run benchmarks.

If I follow the guide's instructions to the letter, I add this to my Gemfile:

> gem 'ruby-prof', :git => 'git://github.com/wycats/ruby-prof.git'

...and get version 0.11.0 from the wycats repository. When I run my test I get this error:

```
/Users/craig/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/ruby-prof-ffae61a89553/lib/ruby-prof/abstract_printer.rb:44:in `inspect': undefined method `to_s' for #<Class:0x000001025a3f18> (NoMethodError)
from /Users/craig/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bundler/gems/ruby-prof-ffae61a89553/lib/ruby-prof/abstract_printer.rb:44:in `full_name'
...
```

But "wycats" doesn't appear to be the canonical Github repo for ruby-prof. The documentation refers to [rdp](https://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof) (Roger Pack). If I use that repo instead:

> gem 'ruby-prof', :git => 'git://github.com/rdp/ruby-prof.git'

...I get version 0.11.2, and get this error:

> /Users/craig/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/testing/performance/ruby.rb:39:in `run': undefined method`values' for [#]:Array (NoMethodError)
>       from /Users/craig/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.1.0/lib/active_support/testing/performance.rb:140:in `run_profile'
>   ...

I get the same error if I just use the gem from rubygems directly (again, version 0.11.2):

> gem 'ruby-prof'

Any ideas what's going wrong, or how to resolve it?

> 

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To use latest ruby-prof version you need rails 3.2.3, I don't know what ruby-prof version you can use with rails 3.1, maybe you can copy lib/active_support/testing/performance/ruby.rb from activesupport 3.2.3

Answer (score 8):

The problem is in activesupport-3.2.2\lib\active_support\testing\performance\ruby.rb.

Change line 39 from:

```
@total = @data.threads.sum(0) { |method_infos| method_infos.max.total_time }
```

To:

```
@total = @data.threads.sum(0) {|thread| thread.top_method.total_time}
```

Comment: awesome! thanks so much. Is this patch submitted to rails, out of curiousity?

Answer (score 4):

Ruby on Rails 3.2.6 has this already corrected.
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.6/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/performance/ruby.rb

line 39

```
@total = @data.threads.sum(0) { |thread| thread.methods.max.total_time }
```

in Rails 3.2.3
https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.3/activesupport/lib/active_support/testing/performance/ruby.rb

it is:

```
@total = @data.threads.values.sum(0) { |method_infos| method_infos.max.total_time }
```

and looks like the **values** method is failing here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I fixed by installing the correct ruby-prof version for my Rails version.

So, I was using Rails 3.0.9 released on June 16th, 2011 (as per https://rubygems.org/gems/rails/versions).

Then, I checked for ruby-prof released around that same date. And it was 0.10.8 released on July 6, 2011.

After installing the above I got it working. Some of the profiling metrics might not be supported.

Cheers.

Comment: @coder I went through the Faq. Did not see anything I missed in my answer. Can you highlight if something is missed.

Comment: Yes, there was the wrong ruby-prof version in my case, and your solution helped me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case with Rails 3.2.9, I removed auto-generated directory 'test/performence' from my project.